# failed to find '@attr/TextAppearanceButton' in current theme

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-xml

I want to add Extended floating action button to my android project app but got an error saying failed to find `@attr/TextAppearanceButton` in current theme. I have implemented material dependency in build.grade module. I am new to Android Development. Please I need a help .

Comment: provide some more code please

Comment: Add your code, your build.gradle and your app theme

Answer (score 3):

change your styles.xml to like below

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the issue of rendering xml files after updating my android studio to DOPLPHIN.

In your xml, add android:theme="@style/YOUR_MATERIAL_THEME" to your parent layout and all rendering issues will be gone.

```
                   OR
```

In your manifest file under <application add android:theme="@style/YOUR_MATERIAL_THEME"

I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Adding the theme `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"` to my parent layout saved me from going bonkers, thanks @Sourabh.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to them by **?attr/** and not **@attr/**. Example - **?attr/colorPrimary**.